# Issue with creating TinyMCE within an Iframe in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, iframe

I’m simply trying to create a TinyMCE (4.1.7) for a textarea within an Iframe. Actually this works fine in Firefox and Chrome but not for the Internet Explorer. When I separately call the Iframe in a new Tab everything behaves as expected even in the Internet Explorer but as soon as I’m trying to do the same with Iframe it fails.

The binding I do with the following snippet:

```
    tinymce.init({ mode: 'textareas', theme: 'modern', toolbar: 'bold italic underline strikethrough bullist numlist', menubar: false, });
```

There is also no error in the console that’s why I’m assuming the Internet Explorer is not able to correctly resolve the element for the binding.
I’ve also tried different modes for adding and even the concrete element ID. All are working for a normal page in the IE, but as soon as I put it into the Iframe it’s not working anymore.

Does anyone has noticed the problem and could solve it somehow?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! Obviously the IE 8 isn’t able to handle dynamically loading of the tinymce sources shortly before executing them. Now I’m including the script directly in the HTML and it's working. For IE9 also the dynamic way feasible.